# Regarding table lock while running stored procedure sequentially

Tags: sql-server

I have 15 stored procedures that contain

```
Insert into table1
select (some functions like splitstring, date calculation) 
from table2 d, table3 r, table2 d1, table3 r1)

Update table2
set date = calcualteddate
```

15 stored procedures using the same tables (table2, table3 and its child version like self join)

While running all these stored procedures, the table2 gets locked so we aren't able to do any process in application because of this

SQL Server --> is any clues to avoid this situation?

Comment: The table almost certainly doesn't get locked -- the engine is smart enough to lock only affected rows. The first thing to do in a situation like this is to review the indexes on your table, to ensure none of the statements has to scan far more rows than necessary -- the longer statements run, the more opportunity there is for locking conflicts. If that's all fine and the remaining concern is that readers can't access the table because it's continuously updating, [snapshot isolation](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server) can help.

Comment: I faced similar issue few years ago. In my case table2 had small amount of data(<10K) and following 2 things helped us to solve the issue:

1. create index on date.
2. use rowlock in query.

Comment: @jereon , In this case update its not taking too much time only select statement with some functions took more time. In case of INDEX ing all fields are having index. but in select Query they are using UPPER,like functions with union all

Comment: @rahul how to use rowlock query n mssql. can u pls provide me a link

Comment: you can check: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/07/26/sql-server-observation-rowlock-hint-and-slow-performance/

Comment: using rowlock also its not improving, actually they are using column varachat(max) in the where clause is there any way to add index for this column to improve the performance. I have searched its not possible to add index for nvarchar(max) datatype. but xid nvarchar(max) contains integer values sometime its like 1,2,2, or 1|2|6  is there any way to index this column?